# Outlook 2013 view settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I am quite happy using Outlook 2013, however there is a thing bothering me - hopefully someone can help me get this adjusted.

Basically I see my own name in the Sent items folder, I would like to have this adjusted to see the recepients name instead of my own. Is there a possibility to change this around?

Kindly see this image as reference:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is `Change` the view.

I have Outlook 2010, so some things may appear different, but the concept is the same. To change the view, select the `Sent Items` folder, switch to the `View` tab, click `Change View`, then `Sent`.

[image]

If that doesn't work, do the same thing again, except this time choose `Rest View`. This will reset the view to default.

After that, if it still has not worked, you can use these instructions to change it manually - [Sent Items folder only shows my name](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/49).

Comment: This is outstanding - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably displaying the "To" column instead of the "From" column.  Right click any column name and choose view settings. Click the Columns button and modify which columns are being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In the conversation settings, uncheck messages from other folders and you do not see the message sent by you (since those will be in the sent items folder)